# How to get project GUID in runtime of .netcore?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm the newer of .netcore.

Now, I have a sql connection string using guid to encrypt, and I generate a guid in project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <ProjectGuid>{D830E0EE-9D0B-4FC2-A609-4661990159D2}</ProjectGuid>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then, I want to get it when runtime for decrypt, and I try to do below:

```
object[] guids = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), false);
string guid = ((GuidAttribute)guids[0]).Value;
```

The `GetCustomAttributes` could not use in here, because it is not `assembly`.

How can I do anything?

Thx.

Comment: Project GUID is only used to show the type of the project so that the tooling around MSBuild/VS can properly handle it. It is never embedded into assemblies as attributes. So back to your intention, why do you need that?

Comment: because our's project always use guid to encrypt/decrypt sql connection password.

Comment: Using public information for encryption... That's feels somewhat awkward.

Comment: I know.., but it's a old project and this project for internal use, so..

Answer (score 0):

This information is not compiled into your application and not available at runtime.

If you bundle a secret with your application, it will not be secret because no extra privileges are needed to load the secret into memory.

If you use SqlServer use Integrated Security. In that case, you don't deal with passwords at all and the user account is used. Such mechanism is available to many database systems, even if you don't use SqlServer.